# Past participle form "geschlossenen"

Tags: adjective, past-participle

Someone asked about a statement in a book.

> Die Firmen, die seit Jahren geschlossenen sind, verschmelzen zu einem
> Konzern.

In this statement, why is it `geschlossenen` not `geschlossen`?

Comment: I was able to find a few similar examples via DWDS: Wenn die Augen geschlossenen sind, klingt das Geräusch wie das ferne Rollen der Brandung. (Die Zeit, 28.01.2009, Nr. 4) *Kein vernünftiger Mensch sollte jemanden, der sich in einer verzweifelten und hungernden Stadt aus Geschäften, die auf unbestimmte Zeit geschlossenen sind, Lebensmittel holt, zum „Plünderer“ erklären, doch genau das haben die Medien unablässig getan.* (Die Zeit, 08.09.2005, Nr. 37(

Comment: The sentence has another weakness in phrasing: while a shop as well as a restaurant can be closed easily, for companies other verbs are significantly more appropriate: *Pleite gehen*, *vom Markt verschwinden*, *aufgeben*, *sich auflösen*, which are all kind of final, but few companies continue to exist while making no business.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a mistake. "Geschlossen" = Partizip, "Geschlossenen" = Adjectiv, Genitiv Sing. or Pl., Dativ Sing. or Pl., Accusativ Sing. or Pl.

Answer (score 7):

It is just wrong. Maybe someone messed up when they made the book.

Comment: This is a bit short for an answer. Given that the major part boils down to an assumption (even if plausible), you may want to add some substance to discourage deletion.

Answer (score 1):

*Geschlossen* is the participle, that is the past participle. In this context *geschlossen* seem to be the correct version.

I found the usage of *geschlossenen* in few other instances like:

1. Zu Beginn des **geschlossenen** Beta-Tests werden wir ein paar Stunden lang einen Lasttest durchführen
2. Zurück zu den **geschlossenen** Wahllisten?

Comment: Where did you find the usage? In case it is online, please add the link to your answer. Do you think "geschlossen" is correct or are you very sure = you know it?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Copy each sentence and paste it to any good search engine. This needs less time than writing a comment. The first sentence can be found [here](https://www.playlostark.com/de-de/news/articles/closed-beta-details) and [here](https://stevinho.justnetwork.eu/2021/11/02/lost-ark-der-pre-download-fuer-die-beta-startet-heute/), the second is the title of this page [here](https://wochenblatt.cc/zurueck-zu-den-geschlossenen-wahllisten/).